# GNOME Tweak Tool

Tags: gnome, mouse, freeze, gnome-tweak-tool

I have just installed GNOME Tweak Tool by typing this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

After installing I have applied few tweaks but after rebooting my Ubuntu 13.10 got error at the time of startup, and then my screen desktop become blank. Even changing desktop images doesn't work for me. And my system gets freezes many times. And my mouse right properties also doesn't show up.

Please help me either to learn how to uninstall it or fix it. I am a newbie here.

Comment: There's a Unity Tweak tool which works well. Don't know how to restore your previous settings though.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told ud which settings you changed

Comment: I only applied a few changes that are under the option of that software like changes cursur to red somthing like that and sytem theme

Comment: well, it is clear that you did not use it to change settings outside of the options of the program ;) but can you recall it more specific? Anyway, I think your problems will be over if you return to default settings, because you probably picked some incompatible combinations. let us know if you don't remember.

Comment: @jcob Firts of all thnx a lot for reply. Yes i only tweak few setting available under that app but  dont know what the changes i made please help me retore it. These changes become unstable for my system

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer, because I need to post some images.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have set some incompatible setting combination(s). Gnome Tweak Tool can be used on Ubuntu, but is not exclusively for Ubuntu + Unity. That is why there is no "set to default" option, like you would expect from an application, dedicated to Ubuntu only. Removing the application would not undo the setting changes you made with it.

Since you mentioned you changed the Theme-settings, below are the default settings in the Theme-section. If you return to these settings, you will probably have no more problems after you log out and in.

```
Theme section of the Gnome Tweak Tool:

    Current theme           Ambiance
    Cursor theme            DMZ-White
    Gtk+ Keybinding Theme   Default
    Icon Theme              Unity-icon-theme
    Gtk+ Theme              Ambiance
```

Comment: Thanx a loat for giving ur pricius time on my problem. Hope this work for me.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. could u tell me how to uninstall that software with command line and could u suggest me any good tweak tool for me.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to access command line interface. When asked to login, enter the regular username and password. Open Terminal and run the following commands:

rm -rf ~/.config
mv ~/.config Documents/Backupcfg
sudo reboot

I hope that any of the above methods should solve the problem.